# does RTK Query maintain order of results dependent on order of requests (FIFO)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a React component where the data are fetched using `RTKQuery`. The same `useFetchQuery` is used multiple times depending on the change of the `deviceData` prop.

I need to maintain the same order of requests results as the request initiations (`FIFO`). It can happen that some fetch requests take longer than others, so there is a possibility that result of the first one will come after second one. So the question is, **does RTKQuery maintain order of the results** in this case?

Here I have the simplified code:

```
const DataFetchComponent = ({deviceData}) => {

    const [queryId, setQueryId] = useState(null)
    const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([])

    const { data: receivedData } = useFetchQuery({ id: queryId } , {skip: !queryId}) 

    useEffect(() => {
        setQueryId(deviceData.id)
    }, [deviceData]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setProcessedData([...processedData, receivedData])
    }, [receivedData]);
}
```

**Note:** The original code is much more complex, so different solution like marking each received data with id key is not possible here.

Comment: "does RTKQuery maintain order of the results" - No, it doesn't. From what I can understand of your question, if you are wanting to "capture & save" each individual query result then perhaps you want to instead use a lazy query, trigger a query with specific parameter, and wait for it's result and enqueue the local state update. It's up to you to use whatever data structure you need to maintain any specific data order.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be horribly inperformant as usually you want to display data as soon as it's available and not to stall for 30 seconds just because some other query stalls for 30 seconds.

Your example here doesn't make it clear what you really want to do though - that `useQuery` hook will only ever return new results for the value you are passing in right now anyways, so there is no way you'd ever have multiple results for multiple requests arriving here.

Also, that `useEffect` seems to tie logic that probably doesn't belong into your component inside of your component. Are you sure you don't want to work with the endpoint lifecycle instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem, there was indexing problem whiling mapping array then you should put unique key for per item.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDZAO.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).